# Limit of binomial coefficient by using Integral of cos^n

Tags: analysis, limits, binomial-coefficients

I want to prove the following:

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} 2^{-2n} \sqrt{n} \binom{2n}{n} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$

I know that I can use $I_n=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}(cos(x))^ndx$ and I already proved $nI_n=(n-1)I_{n-2}$ and $I_{n-1}I_n=\frac{\pi}{2n}$.

Now I'm struggling to get this together and need some help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals You can finally prove that $I_n \sim \sqrt {\frac {\pi}{2n}}$

Comment: distinguish $I_{2n}$  and $I_{2n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
You can use [Stirling's approximation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html) to prove that, $$\binom{2n}{n}\sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}.$$